# Checking images for corruptions

Tags: image-quality, windows

Is there a tool that can be used for batch checking images for corruptions such as these (in this case, occured due to error while moving file),

[image]

Comment: Additionally, are there other types of corruptions that can occur in an image, while the file still remaining viewable (the types of corruptions which to detect, I would have to go through the images one by one to see. In defition of corrution I'm not counting images out of focus and such... but these, "technical kind")?

Comment: @mattdm - Possible. Unfortunatelly, neither of the answers there answer the question - one is UNIX only, one does not answer the question and one suggests manual viewing. Personally, I think this question is better formed and already has a better answer, which I'm currently exploring.

Comment: It's still the exact same question. And I see now that _you_ even asked it! See [How Do I “Refresh” a Question?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/how-do-i-refresh-a-question)

Comment: And, while the primary tool I suggested in my answer to the other question isn't natively for Windows, I think it will _build_ in Windows fine. The other part of my answer covers a tool which is only available in Windows/Mac.

Comment: @mattdm - How would I go about building it in Windows environment? Could you give a short sentence or two on that?

Comment: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/howto

Comment: @mattdm - If I understood correctly, I would need to install mingw and use it to build jpeginfo. But that would just build another unix tool, so I couldn't make an exe to use under Windows from it? Or do I have it completely wrong. Afraid to admit, I haven't used UNIX much.

Comment: MinGW builds Windows binaries from code wrote for a Unix-like environment.

Comment: @mattdm - This is useless, I give up. From installing mingw, git, to trouble with creating a directory named aux - then installing cygwin just to try to avoid that restriction, to trouble with building jpeginfo, ... I have been five days on this now, and really think I shouldn't be an experienced programmer just to be able to use a simple image verification tool.

Comment: Did you really just vote down my answer on the other question because you're having trouble buildings one of the tools I suggested on your operating system? I mean, I don't need the rep, but that seems a bit misplaced.

Comment: @mattdm - Yes; nothing personal (I know it sounds like a cliche, but in this case really it isn't.) but I just spend a good part of the week trying to build/install something that, it seems, cannot be done. I would love to be proven wrong, to that I even posted a question about how to go about it on stackoverflow, but for now... to someone else looking for an answer to the same question, jpeginfo as an answer will do little good. Also downloaded another answer that suggested viewing images manually, while being technically correct it does little good in practice.

Comment: @mattdm - I'm still going to pursue the way to try to build it on Windows, if I find out how - with your permission, I'll edit your answer and then upvote it for it did originally suggest jpeginfo. Does that seem fair to you? If you find a way to build it in the meantime, same applies.

Comment: I added a link to a blog post where someone else built it just fine in Cygwin and provided downloads. And, of course, the answer should work just fine on Mac or Linux.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools for detecting corrupted images, but It depends on the file type you want to check since each image type has its own compression method and therefore has its own integrity checks. I did a quick search on superuser and came up with [this](https://superuser.com/questions/276154/automating-the-scanning-of-graphics-files-for-corruption). Hope that answers your question.

See also:

- [Is there a tool to check the file integrity of a series of images?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46919/is-there-a-tool-to-check-the-file-integrity-of-a-series-of-images)
- http://watson-net.com/blog/checking-the-integrity-of-all-jpg-files-in-a-directory/
- http://www.dpbestflow.org/data-validation/data-validation-details#data

Answer (score 0):

I use the /v flag when copying the files from the card, which compares the copy against the original after copying.

I copy to a NAS that has its own protection against silent changes: ZFS applies a checksum to every data parcel.  Without such under-the-hood automation, you can generate a file of hash codes (e.g. SHA-2) and periodically check them again.  I've used featues built into the "4NT" (now Take Command) command shell to do this on Windows.